# Changing cleveref's format on an individual basis

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

Is it possible to change [`cleveref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref?lang=en)'s `\crefpairconjunction` on a one-off basis. By default, `\cref{eqn:1,eqn:2}` outputs "eqs. 1 and 2". I would like to change this to "eq. 1 or 2" on just one occasion without affecting other cross-references.

Comment: For a single case it may be easier to use normal `ref`s and write it manually: `eqs. \ref{eqn:1} or \ref{eqn:2}`.

Comment: You can localize the effect of changing the definition of `\crefpairconjunction` by scoping. So `\begingroup \renewcommand*{\crefpairconjunction}{ or~} \cref{eqn:1,eqn:2} \endgroup` would work.

Comment: I actually am in favor of @Marijn's idea ;-)

Comment: @Marijn For sure that would be easiest. I'm just asking for the OCD solution. Also, if it's something not easily possible with `cleveref` right now, it might lead Toby Cubitt to consider adding this functionality in the next update.